# How to Get Around GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE for Image Processing

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, post-processing

I am developing an image processing program which relies on OpenGL ES 2.0 so it may be deployed on a large spectrum of devices. In many occasions, people will use small images and this will not bypass the texture limit, but with larger images that are thousands of pixels in each direction, it may not be able to render on multiple devices.

My first thought was to split the image into smaller squares and render each of those individually which would work for simple programs, but for tasks that need to render based on neighboring pixel values such as convolutions or warping effects, this won't be sufficient.

How does Photoshop keep their 300,000 x 300,000 dimension capability with adding OpenGL support in their application for many of their effects?

What is the most efficient way to perform post-processing tasks on images larger than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?

Rendering to only the viewable area and rescaling images for zoom before sending them to be processed? but this would require me to re-process the image for simple zoom in/out and panning around the image. The only problem I see with this approach is that there is no way to export the image as a full quality image, so this method works well up until the user tries to save their work.

Comment: For tiling when convolutions are involved, you can add a buffer around the edges of your tiles so that the correct pixels are still sampled near those edges. The buffer regions add a little processing and memory overhead, and they don't allow for an arbitrary sampling distance (most visible in a long-range warping operation), but short-range convolutions and things like Gaussian blurs can be made to work using this.

Answer (score -3):

the problem is that opengl is for real-time rendering and not fit for image processing, the best choice is using the CPU program and all its benefits (C/C++, threading, no texture limits, ..) only consider opengl in case of 'helping' the CPU (like NVIDIA CUDA).

Comment: Meh, since he talks about ES-devices, OpenGL and the good old GPGPU fragment shader approach (what everybody did before CUDA) is still the best option for GPU-accelerated image processing. And in fact this approach is perfectly fit for simple image processing tasks (though synchronization and feedback could get difficult for more complex tasks).